# I have searched a lot but still unable to understand the concept of returning const int * or const char *

Tags: c++

i know this that has been asked a lot of times.But its really confusing for me so when a function returns a pointer does it means that it is returning an address if so how does writing const in return makes it constant that it cannot change content at that memory address

```
const int * fun()
{
   return &y; // where y is a data member of a class
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does

Comment: What in particular don't you understand?

Comment: I guess your confusion is how this works. A const pointer looks exactly like a non-const pointer, as you say it's just an address. How it works is that the **compiler** makes sure that you cannot change what is being pointed to (at least not without cheating). Once your program runs there are only machine addresses and nothing at the hardware level is making anything const, it's only the compiler that is protecting you.

Comment: Also note that returning a const pointer does **not** make the object being pointed to const. All a const pointer means is that you cannot change the object **through that pointer**. There's nothing to stop you changing the object some other way.

Answer (score 2):

`const int * fun()` returns a pointer to an int. You can modify the pointer, but you cannot modify the value it points to. For returning a single `int` this might be of little value, because you could return a copy of that `int` instead.

But consider the case of returning a pointer to a `char` sequence. Returning a pointer to non-const `char` would allow the caller to modify what it points to - which is a bad idea if it actually points to a string literal like `"foo"`.

A comment to the question says `const int *` is a const pointer. This is a bit confusing. To be precise: it is a (modifiable) pointer to a read-only `int`.

A const pointer (i.e. a pointer you cannot modify) would be `int * const`.

Unfortunately, C++ allows both `const foo` and `foo const` meaning the same. IMHO it is better to always adopt the left-associative form, i.e. `foo const`. So,

- `foo const` is a constant `foo` (as is `const foo`)
- `foo const*` is a (modifiable) pointer to a constant `foo`
- `foo * const` is a read-only pointer to a modifiable `foo`
- `foo const * const` is a read-only pointer to a read-only foo.